# How to invite my partner to visit me in the UK?

Tags: visas, uk

I want my Palestinian partner to visit me in the UK, I am a UK citizen who is unemployed and living in the UK. My partner is not officially working and only receives commission so does not have bank statements for the application process. Can my parents invite him and pay for his trip to the UK? Or what other way can he get a visa to visit me?

Comment: Good luck, if the two primary parties (you and your partner) are unemployed, a visa will be nigh impossible.  As he has no job, his support is coming from the UK, you live in the UK, there is very little to prove he is certain to return home.

Comment: So even if he has a savings account and my parents invite/ sponsor/ offer to pay for his stay in UK and he can verify he has work to return to?

Comment: I understand your partner is not officially working, but what exactly are they doing to receive commissions?

Comment: You said he was not officially working, so how will he suddenly be able to prove he has a job that mandates his return?  The biggest issue with visas is proving he is going home and not moving to the UK.

Comment: Commission is from real estate rentals. However this varies every month, he is under the sponsorship from his old employer in Qatar who agreed to let him work for another company

Comment: If he has a big savings account, that would be points in his favor in terms of supporting himself, but nothing in favor of proving he will go home.

Comment: Not to be rude, it it some kind of internet romance ? Based on his condition, it doesn't seem he will get a visa easily. So why don't you visit him instead, it will be much easier.

Comment: So he really needs to be able to prove he needs to return after his visit in terms of his employment? I met his 3 years ago when I worked in Qatar but its not an option for me to go back there due to my family commitments here in the UK.

Comment: @user54729, it will all come together. Travel to other western countries without overstay will help. A steady job at home will help. The appearance of being a respectable businessman will help. No single factor is enough.

Answer (score 3):

You have to convince the visa officials that your partner can pay for the trip **and** that he will return home at the end of the visit. Unfortunately there are many people who would overstay if they were given an opportunity, so it is not enough to state that one would *of course* follow the law.

So they will ask your partner to show ties to his homeland.

- Among the best possible ties is a stable, well-paid job.
- Owning real estate would help.
- It would also help if he had dependents at home which do not come along on a (business) trip.
- Having a partner in the UK does not help, since it creates incentives to overstay.